# Selenium Test Commandline

Tags: user-interface, selenium

How do i post the results to a URL via the "selenium-server.jar"

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "https://www.myserver.com/rc/" "/selenium/Tests/TestSuite2.html" "http://myserver.com/readSeleniumResults"

chrome://src/content/TestRunner.html?auto=true&multiWindow=true&defaultLogLevel=info&baseUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myserver.com%2Frc%2F&resultsUrl=http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/postResults&test=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4444%2Fselenium-server%2Ftests%2FUI_TestSuite2.html
```

I would like the &resultsUrl to be "&resultsUrl=http://myserver.com/readSeleniumResults"

Answer (score 1):

There's no way Selenium can be able to report the results of the tests to an online site.
If you think it, you'll soon notice there isn't a standard way for which selenium could take care of such task.

I recommend you wrapping that system call inside a script, that once selenium finished takes care of sending the results html file through FTP or the method you've chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing.

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar  -htmlsuite *iexplore http://yourwebsite c:\testsuite\BasicTestSuite c:\testsuite\results.html
```